# In Codeigniter : How to Count in table using Join in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables company,rate

Company has two columns-

- v_id
- company_name

user_ratings has three columns

- r_id
- v_id
- rate

**In this rate v_id column,I have  company_id (v_id) which has two different rating and when i count the ratings for one company every time i am getting only one. How to count the ratings for company.**

```
function get_list() {

        $this->db->select('company.company_name, COUNT(user_ratings.rate) as rate');
        $this->db->from('company_details');
        $this->db->join('user_ratings', 'company.v_id = user_ratings.v_id');
        $this->db->group_by('company.company_name, rate');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return  $query->result();
    }
```

Comment: Its return only one record from user rating table because of goup_by..try after removing group by

Comment: you can also follow below answer..

Comment: after removing group by i am getting error like  In aggregated query without GROUP BY

Answer (score 1):

You have grouped results with both `company_name` and `rate`. This is why it's returning count as 1 for all records. Grouping only by company name will return desired results.

Change this

```
$this->db->group_by('company.company_name, rate');
```

to

```
$this->db->group_by('company.company_name');
```

Also, `company` is used as an alias for `company_details` table but its not created.

```
$this->db->from('company_details AS company');
```

Comment: It's giving proper data. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/757778/2. For company ID 3 there is only 1 rating, so rate value is 1. For company ID 1 there are 2 ratings, so rate value is 2.

Comment: i am little bit shocked, Because this query is running on sqlfiddle But on mysql this  query is throwing error.

Comment: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'search.company.v_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Remove sql mode (FULL_GROUP_BY) from your sql config file

Comment: Thank You Guys.. i Don't need to remove (FULL_GROUP_BY) .